# How to call function from magento backend when changing options?

Tags: function, magento, model, backend

How can I call function from my module when I change something in backend ? For example I change some customer attribute from 'no' to 'yes', and when I do that I want to call function from `app/code/local/mycompany/extends/controllers/AccountController.php` which changes some other attribute and sends email to customer.

This is the field in BE:

```
$this->addColumn('b2b_client', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('B2B Client'),
        'index'     => 'b2b_client',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'options' => array(
            0 => 'No',
            1 => 'Yes',
        )
    ));
```

and the field I want to update when this is changed is 'Associate to Website'.

Comment: Is that an excerpt from Grid.php _prepareColumns() ? If so, does that mean that you want to edit your customer in the grid? Why didn't you made an Edit.php with an Edit/Form.php and added your custom functionality on the save action?

Comment: because I don't know how to do that ;D

Comment: Check out this tutorial http://codegento.com/2011/02/grids-and-forms-in-the-admin-panel/
Or google for magento adminhtml grid with form and see more tutorials like the one above